# How to write a small List of Strings into a file on HDFS?

Tags: scala, hdfs

I wrote the following function which aims at writing a list of Strings into HDFS, but I am facing some difficulties:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.io._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream

def fileFromList(input: String, outputPath: String) = {
  val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
  val path = new Path(outputPath)
  val output= hdfs.create(path)
  val outt = new BufferedOutputStream(output)
  outt.write(input.getBytes)
  outt.close()
  hdfs.close()
}
```

But when I try to use an input of type List[String] I get compilation errors.

Here is an example of input list I try to store:

```
val input = List(
  "banana apple strawberry",
  "Apple banana strawberry"
)
```

which I would like to save in this exact file:

```
val outputpath = "/folder/test.YMSL"
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to join your input `List[String]` as a `String` joined with `'\n'`:

```
List("banana apple strawberry", "Apple banana strawberry").mkString("\n")
res0: String = "banana apple strawberry\nApple banana strawberry"
```

---

In addition, the `FSDataOutputStream` that you create from the [`FileSystem.create`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) method, actually has a `write` method which allows you to directly write in a file on hdfs.

So no need to create the `BufferedOutputStream` stream.

---

I'm used to keep this helper around:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

def writeToHdfsFile(content: String, filePath: String): Unit = {
  val outputFile = FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).create(new Path(filePath))
  outputFile.write(content.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  outputFile.close()
}
```

alongside with:

```
def writeToHdfsFile(seq: Seq[String], filePath: String): Unit =
  writeToHdfsFile(seq.mkString("\n"), filePath)
```

which can be called this way:

```
writeToHdfsFile(
  List("banana apple strawberry", "Apple banana strawberry"), 
  "/folder/test.YMSL"
)
```